# One of a kind necklace - Business Slogan

Tags: grammatical-number, slogan

i'm working on a business slogan and seeking for native english support with it. 
we would like to use "one of a kind necklaces" - meaning that every necklace we sell is unique as slogan. 
The question is now.... do we need to write "one of a kind necklace" or "one of a kind necklaces" (plural?)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you please add more detail? The answer depends on context.

Comment: That's the problem... its out of context. Should be written on a business card. So company name and then "one of a kind necklaces". To be used like a slogan.

Comment: bespoke is being used increasingly for one-of-a-kind—check it out

Comment: @Xanne - But *bespoke* leans toward custom-made rather than just “every one is different”

Comment: @Jim Bespoke was originally used to describe custom-made men’s suits, but has spread far wider.

Comment: @Xanne - I agree that it goes beyond men’s suits, but it still means custom made as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Jim I see your point—unique but not custom made.

Answer (score 1):

You could use either.

> We make one of a kind necklaces
>
> Every piece we make is a one of a kind necklace.

If the phrase has to stand on its own then "*one of a kind necklaces*" implies that there are more than one unique necklace on offer, but "*one of a kind necklace*" is referring to a single, specific item.

Answer (score 0):

It would be written "one-of-a-kind necklaces" but "unique necklaces" sounds better.
Can you fit "unique and original necklaces" on the card?
Using an ampersand for the "and" looks nice. 
"original & unique necklaces" also fine.

Comment: I'm upvoting this because it is the only post (other than Xanne's first comment beneath the posted question) that hyphenates "one-of-a-kind" when using it as a modifier.